# PHP array cast on foreach doesn't pass variable by reference

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, casting

Please consider this test:

```
$data=[["id"=>1,"text"=>"One"],["id"=>2,"text"=>"Two"]];
foreach((array)$data as &$iter)
    $iter["append"]=true;
print_r($data);
```

This is the output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [text] => One
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [text] => Two
        )

)
```

I want to iter over an array and add another key inside the associative array, this is why $iter is passed by ref.
I set the cast inside the "foreach" to be sure that an empty/null variable can be accepted without errors by foreach statement.

As you see in the output the foreach doesn't append the value, but if I remove the cast it works.

```
foreach($data as &$iter)
    $iter["append"]=true;
print_r($data);
```

This is the (right) output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [text] => One
            [append] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [text] => Two
            [append] => 1
        )

)
```

I solved casting with a separate command outside the foreach, but my question is:

**Is this a bug?**

This test was run on PHP Version 5.6.14 (apache-2.4 windows-10)

Comment: The casted value can be a different value than what's inside the variable. So if it *would* work it would implicit assign: `$variable = (array) $variable;`.

Comment: Ok, but different values means different reference?

Comment: Exactly it's a value and you can't pass that via [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php). Just as example if your variable holds: `$variable = new StdClass;` And your first code block works, would mean you have done an assignment implicit in the foreach header, which is not going to work, since after that you would have an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting some variable to other type (even the same) means that another variable is created.

So if you have:

```
$data = []; // some array here
```

Then doing  `(array)$data` (what is the same as `array($data)` according to php-manual)  means that you have new variable, so your:

```
foreach ((array)$data as &$iter)
```

works not with `$data` variable, but with some other variable, which still has same values as your `$data`.

So, you should explicitly cast to `array`:

```
$data = (array)$data;
foreach ($data as &$iter) {
    // do some stuff
}
```

And as manual said:

> Array assignment always involves value copying.

so your `$data` and `(array)$data` are not the same.